# Trying to open a PDF with AxAcroPDFLib

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe

I have installed the latest Adobe Reader on my PC (Adobe Acrobat Reader DC).
Now I would like to use AxAcroPDFLib in C# to open and show a PDF file in my Windows Forms application.

The problem is, if I am trying to use the `LoadFile()` method, then it says that this method is not exist.

I loaded the **Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Browser Control Type Library 1.0** COM reference into my project, and I added the **Adobe PDF Reader** COM Component to my toolbox (Tools / Choose Toolbox Items... / COM Components).

[image]

What is wrong? How should I open a PDF file with this library? I found a lot of tutorials on the internet, and everybody tells that I have to use the LoadFile method... Please help, thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use the method and see if you have compiler error or not? (ignore the fact that it doesn't show up in intellisense) It receives an string parameter that should contain the path to a pdf file

Comment: Yes, there is compiler error: "Error 1 'AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF' does not contain a definition for 'LoadFile' and no extension method 'LoadFile' accepting a first argument of type 'AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: Which version of .Net framework is your app using? Try changing the version of .Net framework, may be AxAcroPDFLib LoadFile is not compatible with a certain version of .Net framework.

Comment: .NET 4.0 I tried to change it now to .NET 4.5, but the problem is the same.

Comment: Do you have version 4.5.1?

Comment: Yes I have, I tried it now with no luck. Should I change only the project framework and that's it? Because that's what I am doing.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone still needs a solution. 
I'm using Adobe Acrobat DC and actually have `AxAcroPDF.LoadFile()` method. However, it doesn't work i.e. nothing happenns :/

So, I used `AxAcroPDF.src` property with url for local file

```
axAcroPdf1.src = "file:///c:/my.pdf"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It did.  You could be a hero to a lot of people by spreading that around on the internet.  Search on: AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF "security restrictions prohibit access to untrusted URLs"

Comment: Also it only works when I change Target CPU to x86 under project settings / Compile section.

Answer (score 3):

This is no longer supported in Adobe Reader DC. Install Adobe Reader v11 and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is still possible. You just need to invoke the method differently.

```
public void LoadFile(string path)
{
    this.GetOcx().GetType().InvokeMember("LoadFile", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | 
      BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding, null, this.GetOcx(), new object[1] { path });
}
```

See [this post for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859466/loadfile-method-of-pdf-viewer-control-not-visible)

Comment: Using System.Reflection like this actually worked for me.  Why did some people not like it?

Comment: I think the downvotes are because my original answer just had a link to the source post, instead of the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Cast object representing your control (of type `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF`) to `AcroPDFLib.IAcroAXDocShim` interface:

```
var acro = (AcroPDFLib.IAcroAXDocShim)axAcroPDFControl.GetOcx();
acro.LoadFile(fileName);
```

It appears that all useful methods are now available under this interface. Works if Adobe Reader DC is installed.

A little extension can be defined:

```
public static class AcroExtensions
{
    public static AcroPDFLib.IAcroAXDocShim AsAcroPDF(this AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF source)
    {
        return (AcroPDFLib.IAcroAXDocShim)source.GetOcx();
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
axAcroPDFControl.AsAcroPDF().LoadFile(fileName)
```