# LoadFile method of PDF viewer control not visible

Tags: c#, pdf, reader

I wanted to automate filling of PDF forms.

So I created a WinForms project in VS2013, Added Adobe PDF Reader control, dragged control on to the form.

No errors. Control is displayed on the form.

However in the code of the form when I try to put in:

```
axAcroPDF1.LoadFile
```

The LoadFile method is not visible at all.

The project .NET target is set to 4.5.1. I even tried 4.5 and lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AxHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/System.Windows.Forms.AxHost(v=vs.110).aspx) wraps only the Active X Control. The LoadFile Method is a method from the COM Class from your Adobe Control.

You need to implement this via a [InvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/System.Type.InvokeMember(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void LoadFile(string path)
{
    this.GetOcx().GetType().InvokeMember("LoadFile", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | 
      BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding, null, this.GetOcx(), new object[1] { path });
}
```

where `this` is the AxHost control.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now the PDF is loaded in the control. Now need to figure out how to access the Form in the PDF and fill it in programattically.