# axAcroPdf doesn't contain a definition for loadfile

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe

After about five hours of searching i don't know what is the problem of this line

axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"d:\report.pdf");

i've just got the error telling that axAcroPdf doesn't contain a definition for loadfile, and so src property, any one have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem and found the following post on Stack Overflow:

[Trying to open a PDF with AxAcroPDFLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952970/trying-to-open-a-pdf-with-axacropdflib)

It gives an alternative library to use and also states that this is no longer supported in Adobe Reader DC, but apparently will work if you install Adobe Reader v11 (note I have not tested this)