# How can I get the first page of a PDF that is accessible via a url as a BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, webview2

I want to display the first page as a thumbnail in my MVVM WPF application.
Maybe there is a possibility with WebView2, because I display the complete Pdf elsewhere.

## I tried it with Pdfium.Net SDK example, however it is not possible to do it with a url.

```
using (var pdfDocument = PdfDocument.Load("Url"))
{
    if (pdfDocument.Pages.Count > 0)
    {
        var page = pdfDocument.Pages[0];

        using (var pdfRenderer = new PdfBitmap((int)page.Width, (int)page.Height, true))
        {
            page.Render(pdfRenderer, 0, 0, (int)page.Width, (int)page.Height, Patagames.Pdf.Enums.PageRotate.Normal, Patagames.Pdf.Enums.RenderFlags.FPDF_THUMBNAIL);
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            pdfRenderer.GetImage().Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `RasterCodecs.Load()` method from the LEADTOOLS library loads bitmaps from either image files or document pages, including PDF. (Disclosure: I work for the SDK’s vendor). [This overload](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/co/rastercodecs-load(uri,int).html) takes URI and page number as parameters, so you can use it to get the first (or any) page from the PDF URL. If you would like to try it, you can obtain a free evaluation edition [from this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this on a couple previous projects.  The answer is not as simple as you might hope but it is doable.

I used AxAcroPDFLib which is a windows forms pdf viewer that was still free at the time. This is an ActiveX control that is installed still with Acrobat Reader 9.x  In the most recent project I used v9.2.  [Adobe Acrobat Reader 9](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/acropdf-active-x-control-with-reader-9-0/m-p/1175440)

For your WPF integration you can build a custom control class that inherits from `WindowsFormsHost` [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Inside this custom control you instantiate instance of `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF` and load your pdf in it.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952970/trying-to-open-a-pdf-with-axacropdflib) for more information on loading from url.  The loading code below worked for PDF help files but they were local to the system though it should work for URL also.

The key is that the `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF` control has methods for `setCurrentPage(pagenum)` and `setNamedDest(namedDestination)` that allow you to drill to either a page or a named destination (must be in PDF already). But I believe you need the `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF.setCurrentPage(pageNumber)` method.

The custom control is too much code to post but some pertinent snippets are:

My change current pdf method (where `acrobatViewer` is instance of the activeX control):

```cs
private void ChangeCurrentPdf()
{
    acrobatViewer.LoadFile(PdfFilePath);
    acrobatViewer.src = PdfFilePath;
    acrobatViewer.setViewScroll("FitH", 0);
    acrobatViewer.setShowToolbar(false);
    acrobatViewer.setPageMode("none");
}
```

The SetPage method that sets the page for the loaded pdf...

```cs
 public void SetPage(int pageNumber)
 {
     if (pageNumber < 0)
     {
         pageNumber = 0;
     }
     else
     {
         acrobatViewer.setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
     }
 }
```